# PHP/mysql in xampp apache can not handle large request

Tags: php, apache, networking, xampp, connection

We have a PHP/MYSQL based intranet based product which runs in XAMPP on a LAN. At any given point of time there are more than 150 clients connected to the application and submit forms in POST method. But the problem is that when they submit all their answers at a time, some of them found 'Unable to connect' message on their browser. But I can ping my ip at that time. I believe this is happening because my server PC or xampp apache not able to handle the large number of requests coming at once.

Is it about xampp configuration or network issue??? Can anyone advise what can be the reason of the above issue and what configuration should be changed in order to able to handle more requests and work in more stable and robust mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

There are several reasons of that:

1. reconfigure MySQL for more connections:

   ```
   max_connections=100
   ```

   in `my.cnf` file (should be accessible from xampp panel)
2. Your server spec are to low.
3. bad script optimization.

Also i recommend to check if all connections are closed when not needed anymore.

Set:

```
; Allow or prevent persistent links.
; http://php.net/mysql.allow-persistent
mysql.allow_persistent = Off
```

in `php.ini` file